# Two page entries reference to the same physical page

Tags: windows, linux, mmap

For linux and windows, in the same process, how to make two page entries reference to the same physical page?

For windows, by reading at the MSDN, looks like I can call `CreateFileMapping` by passing `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` to create a file mapping without backed by a file.  Then I can call `MapViewOfFileEx` twice with different `lpBaseAddress`, which essentially makes two different addresses reference to the same physical address.

My question is, how to do it under linux?  I read manual for `mmap`, and didn't see a way to do it, unless the region is backed by a file (with flag `MAP_SHARED`) but modifications to this region will be written to the file, which is not what I want.  Does anyone aware of someway to do this?  I am not against backing by a file, as long as the writing to the region doesn't actually goes to the disk.  Using `tmpfs` is not an option because I can't guarantee user has a `tmpfs` mounted.

By the way, the code should be user mode code, not kernel mode.

Comment: Why? For the life of me, I can't think of a reason why two pointers to the same memory wouldn't work just as well, given that you are a single process.

Comment: @DonGar, the reason is complicated.  In short, I want to write some emulator, and for performance reason, I want to use the hardware memory translation unit to help translating address.  So I need to access the emulated devices' memory via two ways, through physical address (of the emulated devices' memory) and virtual address of the running process in physical.

Comment: Well, you can use mmap with MAP_ANONYMOUS, and even with MAP_FIXED, but I don't know of any way to have a second mapping for the same page. MAP_COPY exists, but not in Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `shm_open()` to create a file for `mmap()`.

"I want to write some emulator" is the same purpose as mine when I used this trick.
I did use ipc/shm, but I forgot the detail. It was very very very very probably: `shmget()+shmat()`